# what data to return from a helper method when copying a file to the system

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a helper method that copies a file to a folder on my web server.

It works, but I'm not quite sure what to return to the method that calls it.

Right now it's just returning true...because maybe it doesn't need to return anything?

Here is the helper method:

```
    public async Task<bool> CopyFile(IFormFile profileUpload, Guid profileId)
    {
        string path = @"D:\ProfilePics\" + profileId;

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await profileUpload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And I call it in my API Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostFormData([FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile profileUpload, Guid profileId)
    {

        if (await _gamerProfile.CopyFile(profileUpload, profileId))
        {
            return Ok();
        } else
        {
            return BadRequest("Please upload a valid file");

        }

    }
```

My question is, is there a better way to handle this?  Is returning true or false ok or should I return another value, or maybe nothing at all?

thanks!

Comment: File operations never work.They throw tons of exceptions as documented. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: If it just returns `true`, then you are forcing your caller to deal with the issue (with the `else` clause that can never be called).  Your file write will be exception prone (it won't call an exception very often, but it can).  If you really wanted a true/false condition, you could catch the exception locally and return false (or false with an error message).  That way, your POST won't return a 500 if the disk fills up, for example.  It's all a question of what you want to do

Comment: @Flydog57 ok so I should put it inside a try catch?  Then if it is successful return true, and if not, then return false?  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can improve the result from the controller in case of failure.

Their is a difference between `BadRequest`(400) and `ServerError`(500).

Bad request mean their is a problem from **user side**, and the user doesn't have any reason to resend without changing the request.

In case of `Server Error` that mean their is a current problem in server, and the user can wait and try again.

Another problem is you are checking in controller that `CopyFile` function return true or false.

But in your code you return only `true`, if you have any problem you will have an exception, not a `false`.

You can add a `try/catch` in you function and return false in case of error.

Comment: thanks so add a try catch inside the CopyFile method?  And return true if it's ok and false if not?

Comment: And you can log the exception